# How can I scrape a WhatsApp emoji using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I know how to webscrape an emoji from WhatsApp but only if:

1. There is a single emoji without any text or

2. there is text with emojis.

But I am unable to webscrape when there are two emojis without any text in a message. This is the html for message ""

```
<div class="JwMbj i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text">
    <span class="_3R6rC">
        <img crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="/img/d07f9aca6938f691b840f97dd1cd67dd_w_638-64.png" alt="" draggable="false"
            class="_2UdhN _1xeoG i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text" data-plain-text=""
            style="visibility: visible;">
    </span>
</div>
```

and I tried this code for getting emoji:

```
m = s.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'i0jNr'})
v = m.find('span', attrs={'class':'_3R6rC'})                         
for i in v.children:
    if isinstance(i, NavigableString):
        print(i)
    elif isinstance(i, Tag):
        print(i.attrs['alt'])
```

but by this code this works only when there is single emoji ,but when there are two emojis in message it prints only one like if the message is "" it gives output as "" (it only prints first emoji) . This is html of that message

```
<div class="JwMbj i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text">
    <span class="_3R6rC">
        <img crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="/img/d07f9aca6938f691b840f97dd1cd67dd_w_1749-40.png" alt="" draggable="false"
            class="_2UdhN _3zyju i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text" data-plain-text=""
            style="visibility: visible;">
    </span>
    <span class="_3R6rC">
        <img crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="/img/d07f9aca6938f691b840f97dd1cd67dd_w_1845-40.png" alt="" draggable="false"
            class="_2UdhN _3zyju i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text" data-plain-text=""
            style="visibility: visible;">
    </span>
</div>
```

I tried this code for printing both the emojis but it doesn't work:

```
msglist = []
m = s.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'i0jNr'}) 
for b in m:
    v = b.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'JwMbj'})   
    for x in v:      
        z = x.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'_3R6rC'})                
        for i in z.children:
            if isinstance(i, NavigableString):
                print(i)
            elif isinstance(i, Tag):
                print(i.attrs['alt'])
```

but it does not give any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `<img>` tags to plain text and then get text normally with `.get_text`. For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="JwMbj i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text">
    <span class="_3R6rC">
        <img crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="/img/d07f9aca6938f691b840f97dd1cd67dd_w_1749-40.png" alt="" draggable="false"
            class="_2UdhN _3zyju i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text" data-plain-text=""
            style="visibility: visible;">
    </span>
    <span class="_3R6rC">
        <img crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="/img/d07f9aca6938f691b840f97dd1cd67dd_w_1845-40.png" alt="" draggable="false"
            class="_2UdhN _3zyju i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text" data-plain-text=""
            style="visibility: visible;">
    </span>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

# select the main text div
text_div = soup.select_one(".copyable-text")

# convert all <img> to plain-text:
for img in text_div.select("img[data-plain-text]"):
    img.replace_with(img["data-plain-text"])

# get text normally:

print(text_div.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

Comment: bro how to get these output if there are many messages ? means that only works when we give html ,so how to get output when there are many msgs? Means if there are four msgs in chat of sender 1)""  2)""  3)"" 4)"" then i tried this code @AndrejKesely

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`   @Andrej Kesely

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\PRANAV PATIL\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')  
driver.get(r'https://web.whatsapp.com/')
input("enter any key :")
searchbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='side']//div//div//label//div//div[@contenteditable='true']")))
searchbox.send_keys('Diksha') #enter your sender's name
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
input("enter any key :")
html_doc = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
ss = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'message-out'})`  @Andrej Kesely

Comment: `if len(ss) > 4:
    ss = ss[-4:]
for s in ss:
    n = s.find('span', attrs={'class':'i0jNr'})
    text_div = n.select_one(".copyable-text")
    for img in text_div.select("img[data-plain-text]"):
        img.replace_with(img["data-plain-text"])
    print(text_div.get_text(strip=True))`  @Andrej Kesely

Comment: this is giving error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select_one'` @Andrej Kesely